# How to use HMVC for Codeigniter 2.1.* when index.php is moved?

Tags: codeigniter, mamp, codeigniter-hmvc

I am trying to build a CodeIgniter application with my index.php inside a "public" folder `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/public/` in the website root. I have setup my vhosts etc to point to this index.php file. I wanted to go for a module based approach and so ended up using [Modular Extensions - HMVC](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc) . I placed the core files and the third party files in the corresponding folders, and created a modules folder in the application folder. I then proceeded to create a "login" module inside the modules folder alongwith the required "controllers/login.php" , "models" and "views"

```
class Login extends MX_Controller{
    public function index()
    {
        log_message('error','reached module');
    }
}
```

Now when i try to load `http://localhost/login` , I get an error log in apache_error.log saying

```
File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/public/login
```

`http://localhost` works fine displaying the welcome screen of CodeIgniter
gniter

This is the path structure :

```
application/modules
└── login
    ├── config
    │   └── routes.php
    ├── controllers
    │   └── login.php
    └── views
        └── login.view.php
```

Content of modules/login/config/routes.php

```
<?php
$route['login'] = 'login';
```

httpd-vhosts config :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/public"
    SetEnv APP_ENV development

    <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use modules::run('module/login', $params, $...) instead of $this->load->view ?

Comment: try some thing  $application_folder = '../application'; just a idea might work, think of where your applications folder is.

Comment: have updated `$application_folder` .. otherwise it would not work from inside the `public`folder

Comment: @Bonatoc - have tried that as well... I added a log message in the index() but it never reached there ..

Comment: is controller in modules folder modules/folder/file in routes may need also to add $route['controllername'] "folder/controllername/index"; and to get default controller or route to work in sub folder just add the index on the end. Must be in modules folder in application.

Comment: @acoderslife : tried it.. but same error. I am beginning to think this does not have anything to do with my CI code but rather my vhosts .. following is my vhosts config( added to question )

Comment: Ok Sorry not sure on vhost I use xammp when developing and then when use cpanel when on main server

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to get my code working. Wrote a small tutorial around it on setting up. You can refer it [here](http://jagzlabs.com/development/php-development/hmvc-codeigniter-secure-index)